# SNS published messages not reaching SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-serverless

I've a encrypted SQS queue and SNS topic by custom managed KMS key. Currently I'm using a similar kind of SQS policy stated in the below link where it is working fine [SQS Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38755387/9896523)

But if i use the below SQS policy it's not working. I don't want to have Principal as '*' due to security reasons. Can someone explain me why is this happening

```
    {
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"MySQSPolicy001",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
  },
      "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This policy will not work for SNS. SNS its not principal `AWS`, but `Service`. The policy from your link is correct, so why not use it?

Comment: But I've allowed all resources part of my account right?

Comment: SNS is not part of your account. Its AWS Service.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 1):

So if you've a condition with SNS arn in your queue policy when more than one topic needs to publish to same queue you might need to add the ARN again & again.

So the workaround will be the below policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Queue1_SendMessage",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:DeleteMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:1234567890:test-queue",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:SourceAccount": "1234567890"
    }
  }
    }
  ]
}
```